# Haskell reuse patterns

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

In the code below, the same pattern match **(Node n left right)** is used by three different functions. If I want to add a pattern, e.g. **(Node n (Leaf) (Leaf))** or change my datatype, I have to change all the functions. Is there a way to reuse these patterns, so I only have to define them once?

```
data Tree = Node Int Tree Tree
          | Leaf 

add :: Tree -> Int -> Tree
add (Node n left right) x = Node (n+x) (add left x) (add right x) 
add (Leaf) x = Leaf

subtract :: Tree -> Int -> Tree
subtract (Node n left right) x = Node (n-x) (subtract left x) (subtract right x) 
subtract (Leaf) x = Leaf

swap :: Tree -> Tree
swap (Node n left right) = Node n right left
swap (Leaf) = Leaf
```

I tried

```
matchNode = (PNode n left right)
add matchNode x = Node (n+x) (add left x) (add right x)
```

but it won't allow me to use the pattern _, and I can't extract **n**, **left**, and **right** from it.

Comment: If you use GHC, you can make use of [Record Wildcards](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-wildcards).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only answers the part:

> If I want to [...] change my datatype, I have to change all the functions.

In that case, you can avoid to change all the functions by
defining a custom pattern with the [pattern synonyms extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#pattern-synonyms):

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

-- The old type:
-- data Tree = Node Int Tree Tree
--           | Leaf 

-- The new type
data Tree = NewNode Tree Int Tree  -- changed name & argument order
          | Leaf

pattern Node n left right = NewNode left n right

add :: Tree -> Int -> Tree
add (Node n left right) x = Node (n+x) (add left x) (add right x) 
add (Leaf) x = Leaf

-- etc.
```

Above, I renamed the old constructor `Node` into `NewNode`, also changing the order of its arguments. Then, I defined a `pattern Node` as a compatibility bridge, making the old patterns below work once again.

---

The question also asks:

> Is there a way to reuse these patterns, so I only have to define them once?

@PyRulez commented on using record wildcards to shorten patterns. Here's a possible way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns, RecordWildCards #-}

-- an auxiliary record type to define the custom pattern 
data R = RNode { left::Tree , n::Int, right::Tree } | RLeaf
-- a function to convert a Tree to a R
toR :: Tree -> R
toR (NewNode l n r) = RNode l n r
toR _ = RLeaf

-- Here we use a shorter pattern:
add2 :: Tree -> Int -> Tree
add2 (toR -> RNode{..}) x = Node (n+x) (add2 left x) (add2 right x)
  -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this brings in scope left, n, right
add2 (toR -> RLeaf) x = Leaf
```

In this specific case, there's not a huge gain in space. However, no matter how large the pattern is, after the record definition (and auxiliary function) we only have to write `toR -> RNode{...}`.

I am not sure I really like this, though.

First, the record pollutes the global name space with three (partial!) functions `left :: R -> Tree, n :: R -> Int, right :: R -> Tree`. This will trigger a few warnings if you try to use e.g. `n` as an argument of another unrelated function (`The local name shadows the global name n`).

Second, the record wildcards extension brings in scope some variables which are not written in the code -- the reader has to know (or guess) what these variables are. Also note that the `RNode{..}` pattern brings e.g. `n` into scope with a different type than the global name: `Int` rather than `R -> Int`. A reader may think that `n` is the global one and be misled even at the type level.

Third, the code above uses view patterns, and these currently confuse the exhaustiveness checker:

```
Patterns.hs:23:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘add2’: Patterns not matched: _ _
```

In this specific case, we could simply write

```
add2 :: Tree -> Int -> Tree
add2 (node -> RNode{..}) x = Node (n+x) (add2 left x) (add2 right x)
add2 _ x = Leaf
```

to avoid the warning, but we do not always have that option, in general.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but pattern synonyms don't allow you to define a more "concise" synonym for `Node n left right` and use that synonym in place of the `Node n left right` pattern in the LHS of equations. Records widlcards, as suggested by PyRulez in his comment, seem closer to what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Ok; I can see how what you describe can be useful in the OP'case.

Comment: @Jubobs I now tried to apply the PyRulez suggestion, so this should answer to the "shortening" part as well.